# Multiple FTP - how to auto upload in PhpStorm?

Tags: ftp, phpstorm

PhpStorm 2016.3.2

Apparently, I can only auto upload files to the FTP marked as "default server".

For example, I have 5 projects and each one has a different FTP server.

How can I do it for every project opened? Otherwise I have to click "tools, deployment, upload to..." every time

EDIT.: That is what I mean by "project"

[image]

Comment: So .. what is the issue? If each project has different default FTP .. then it should be no issues with uploading. Please describe your case in more details.

Comment: Only one server is marked as default, and the others are not auto uploading

Comment: Got it? I have to choose one server only to auto upload, but thats annoying if I am working with more projects

Comment: *"Got it?"* No. In any case: if you have more than 1 deployment server defined in **the same project** .. then auto upload will work with default server only, unfortunately. Here is the ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-5134 .

Comment: What do you mean by `project` in *"if I am working with more projects"* and *"How can I do it for every project opened?"* -- that's what confusing here. **My understanding** is that you working on some shared code (library?) that you wish to upload into multiple sites ("projects" as you call it). Otherwise -- it's not clear what "project" means here .. because in PhpStorm terms "project" is what you are currently working with ("solution" in terns of Visual Studio).

Comment: Look at the edit, and no they are not shared code, they are different from each other. But here for all projects I can use only one default server...

Comment: Just to be clear: I can upload manually every time, but I would like to **auto upload**

Comment: Thanks -- that made it more clear. Unfortunately it's still the same issue (same ticket that I gave before). Thing is -- when you open additional project this way .. only files will be attached as separate node in Project View. But nothing will be done with settings -- they will be ignored and settings from initial/master project will be used for all files. In other words -- projects opened this way are not fully independent -- they all use settings from primary/master project. It's a cheap and limited way of implementing "open multiple project in one window" user request.

Comment: From https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/11/opening-many-project-in-one-frame/ -- *"It’s worth repeating that the interpreter settings and other project-specific configuration such as Docker or Vagrant settings will come from from the top _primary project_."*